# Not showing the greeting message

Tags: php

I was working on my login - register system when i realized i made a problem yet i don't know what it :/
In the index.php page the header should show a welcome guest and link to the login and register page ... and if the gust login show Welcome $username for example.
Yet when i test it ... if i log in it redirect me to the index.php page as i typed in the code yet the msg wont change ...
Here is the codes :
index.php / header.php:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>

<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/test-style.css" TYPE="text/css">

</head>

<body id="body">

<div id="header">
<div id="Greeting">

<?php

       if ($userid && $username) {

              echo "<p>Welcome <b>$username</b></p></p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>";

       } else {

              echo "<p>Welcome Guest <br><a href='login.php'>Log in</a> | <a href='register.php'>Register</a></p>";

       }

?>

</div>
<div id="logo"><h2>Testing website</h2></div>
</div>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Test link 1</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Test link 2</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Test link 3</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Test link 4</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
```

and here is the login.php page :

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(0);
include 'includes/header.php';
?>

<div id="login">
<h2>Log in</h2>

<?php  

    if ($_POST['loginbtn']) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
            if ($user) {
                if ($password) {
                    require ("core/connect.php");
                    $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                        if ($numrows == 1) {
                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                            $dbid = $row['id'];
                            $dbuser = $row['username'];
                            $dbpass = $row['password'];
                            $dbactive = $row['active'];
                                if ($password == $dbpass){
                                if ($dbactive == 1) {
                                    session_start();
                                    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
                                    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                                    header('Location: index.php');
                                  } else {
                                   echo "<font color='red'>You must activate your account to login.</font>";
                                  }
                                 }else {
                                  echo "<font color='red'>You've entered an invalid username or password.</font>";
                                 }
                           }else{
                           echo "<font color='red'>You've entered an invalid username or password.</font>";
                           }
                           mysql_close();
                    }else{
                    echo "<font color='red'>You must enter a password.</font>";
                    }
                } else {
                echo "<font color='red'>You must enter a username.</font>";
                }
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<font color="black">Username: </font><br><input type="text" name="user"><br><br>
<font color="black">Password: </font><br><input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="loginbtn" />
<br><br>
<font color="black">Don\'t have an account ? <a href="register.php">Register</a></font>
</form>
</div>';

<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Best 2 lines in your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(0);`, just think about this, i can't decide which one is better :D

Comment: i did remove them ... no errors ..... hahaha well i use both .... :p better than nothing :p

Comment: Use these lines for error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: userid in C:\wamp\www\test\includes\header.php on line 4
 Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\test\includes\header.php on line 5 These 2 errors .... now what ?

Comment: Here you go ^! You have your error, show us your `header.php` file

Comment: the code that says index.php is the header.php page :) index.php is like empty just include header and footer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your login.php you're using this:

`$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];`

right after `session_start()`

You should initialize them before, like this:

`$userid = $dbid;
$username = $dbuser;`

and them you can set your *$_SESSION*:

`$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`

Comment: nope didnt work :/ or maybe i did something wrong ... please like give me the whole code ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `login.php` replace

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
$_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
```

You actually never set the session variables. Those two line above do that.

Your script needs a lot of work but I just answer the question. Keep learning that's the only way!

Comment: what do you mean need a lot of work ? :o like what ? :o i would love to know what to improve :o

Comment: Well, that was definitely part of the problem. ```$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];``` asks for the content of ```$_SESSION['userid']```, but ```$_SESSION['userid']``` isn't defined anywhere in your code. The line I made you replace fix that issue. You probably have other issues as the comments regarding the error_reporting in your original post state it. header.php seems to have error in it. You should give us that code too.